# Ruby Active Record Association - Getting columns from child table

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have following Association;

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : modules
end

class Module < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : package
end
```

And I use this to get records from the join;

```
@recs = Package.includes(:modules).where( 'name' => 'abc-pkg').all
```

But the resultset, `@recs`, include only parent table's (package) columns. How can I get child (module) table's column?

PS: Using PostgreSQL 9.1 and gem 'pg' adapter

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually correct. You will not see the child's columns inside the `@recs` variable when inspecting it. The point of the `includes` method is to avoid additional queries when iterating over the packages and asking for `package.modules`.

Comment: Thanks @Jiří Pospíšil. Here's what worked;

`@package = Package.where( 'name' => @package_name).first`
`@package.modules.each { |m| puts m.name }`